# 'Inject' one expression into another

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have one expression that's defined like this:

```
Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> firstExpression;
```

and another one like this one:

```
Expression<Func<T1, bool>> secondExpression;
```

`T2` is a value I know, `T1` isn't. What I would like is to make the first expression into the second one, given the value of the parameter `T2`. If it would be regular Linq, it would be this:

```
var t2 = "Something I know";
secondExpression = t1 => fistExpression(t1, t2);
```

How would I do this using `System.Linq.Expressions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by swapping parameter expression with constant expression. Should looks like this

1. implement custom swap ExpressionVisitor

   ```
   public class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
   {
       public Expression From { get; set; }
       public Expression To { get; set; }

       public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
       {
           return node == From ? To : base.Visit(node);
       }
   }
   ```
2. replace parameter T2 with constant

   ```
   var swapper = new SwapVisitor
   {
     From = fistExpression.Parameters[1],
     To = Expression.Constant(val)
   };

   var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
      swapper.Visit(fistExpression.Body), 
      fistExpression.Parameters[0]);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with expression visitor:

```
public static class EmitUtils
{
        private class ParameterReplacerVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            private ParameterExpression _source;
            private Expression _target;

            public ParameterReplacerVisitor(ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
            {
                _source = source;
                _target = target;
            }

            public override Expression Visit(Expression node) =>
                node == _source
                    ? _target
                    : base.Visit(node);
        }

        public static Expression ReplaceParameter(Expression body, ParameterExpression srcParameter, Expression dstParameter) =>
            new ParameterReplacerVisitor(srcParameter, dstParameter).Visit(body);

        public static Expression<Func<T1, T3>> BuildClosure<T1, T2, T3>(Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3>> src, T2 closureValue)
        {
            var constExpression = Expression.Constant(closureValue, typeof(T2));
            var body = ReplaceParameter(src.Body, src.Parameters[1], constExpression);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T3>>(body, src.Parameters[0]);
        }

    }
```

Here is sample usage:

```
        [Test]
        public void ClosureTest()
        {
            Expression<Func<int, string, bool>> CheckStringLength = (len, str) => str.Length < len;
            var constString = "some string";
            var result = EmitUtils.BuildClosure(CheckStringLength, constString);
            Assert.That(result.Compile().Invoke(100), Is.True);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following sample(firstLambda ans secondExpression needed just to see how compiler build the expression)

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Expression<Func<string, int, bool>> firstExpression = (a, b) => a == b.ToString();

    Func<string, int, bool> firstLambda = (a, b) => a == b.ToString();
    Expression<Func<string, bool>> secondExpression = s => firstLambda(s, 45); // this expression I need just to see how it is compiled


    var inputParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s");

    var invocation = Expression.Invoke(firstExpression, inputParameter, Expression.Constant(47));

    var ourBuildExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool> > (invocation, new ParameterExpression[] { inputParameter }).Compile();

    Console.WriteLine(ourBuildExpression("45"));
    Console.WriteLine(ourBuildExpression("47"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I checked in the debugger watch window the result of `Expression<Func<string, bool>> secondExpression = s => firstLambda(s, 45);` it was Invoke expression, so I constructed the same manually.

And you can see the test calls return and print False and True as expected.

Comment: Yes this works, but there's one catch: Expression.Invoke doesn't work with most query providers...